# Need to print different popup text when clicking on different elements

Tags: javascript, html, popup

I have some icons, and when clicking on each one of them I want to show a pop up window with a specific text. The text is different depending on which item are you clicking.

I get to the point in which I the pop up window is properly showing on click, but can't figure out how to connect each text to each icon and display the right one when clicked.

I'm new in this, as you can see, and just trying some things to practice and understand what am I doing. This is what I have so far:

```js
function togglePopup(n) {
  document.getElementById("popup-1").classList.toggle("active");
}
```

```css
.popup .overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
}

.popup .content {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
  background: #fff;
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  z-index: 2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

.popup .close-btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #222;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.popup.active .overlay {
  display: block;
}

.popup.active .content {
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: 2px solid #222;
  color: #222;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!-- DIAMOND GRID  -->
<div class="diamond-grid">
  <div id="diamond-icons">
    <div class="item"><i class="fab fa-html5 skillicon" onclick="togglePopup()"></i></div>
    <div class="item"><i class="fab fa-css3-alt skillicon" onclick="togglePopup()"></i></div>
    <div class="item"><i class="fab fa-bootstrap skillicon" onclick="togglePopup()"></i></div>
  </div>
  <!-- POP UP TEXT -->
  <div class="popup" id="popup-1">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="close-btn" onclick="togglePopup()">&times;</div>
      <h1>HTML</h1>
      <p>I'm getting there</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="popup" id="popup-2">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="close-btn" onclick="togglePopup()">&times;</div>
      <h1>CSS</h1>
      <p>I'm getting there</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="popup" id="popup-3">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="close-btn" onclick="togglePopup()">&times;</div>
      <h1>BOOTSTRAP</h1>
      <p>I'm getting there</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply passing the number of the popup into the function makes the modifications of what you have fairly simple.

Note the html changes to `onclick="togglePopup(1)"` and function accepts the argument to concatenate with the `"popuup-"` string in the id selector

```js
function togglePopup(n) {
  document.getElementById("popup-" + n).classList.toggle("active");
}
```

```css
.popup .overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
}

.popup .content {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
  background: #fff;
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  z-index: 2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

.popup .close-btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #222;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.popup.active .overlay {
  display: block;
}

.popup.active .content {
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: 2px solid #222;
  color: #222;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!-- DIAMOND GRID  -->
<div class="diamond-grid">
  <div id="diamond-icons">
    <div class="item"><i class="fab fa-html5 skillicon" onclick="togglePopup(1)">Item One</i></div>
    <div class="item"><i class="fab fa-css3-alt skillicon" onclick="togglePopup(2)">Item Two</i></div>
    <div class="item"><i class="fab fa-bootstrap skillicon" onclick="togglePopup(3)">Item Three</i></div>
  </div>
  <!-- POP UP TEXT -->
  <div class="popup" id="popup-1">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="close-btn" onclick="togglePopup(1)">&times;</div>
      <h1>HTML</h1>
      <p>I'm getting there</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="popup" id="popup-2">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="close-btn" onclick="togglePopup(2)">&times;</div>
      <h1>CSS</h1>
      <p>I'm getting there</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="popup" id="popup-3">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="close-btn" onclick="togglePopup(3)">&times;</div>
      <h1>BOOTSTRAP</h1>
      <p>I'm getting there</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Perfect!!!!! Was so simple but I just couldn't get to it myself! Need more practice I guess. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Although this was already answered, you might be interested to take a look at a native way without any dependencies.

https://codepen.io/DavidSanek/pen/WNryVZo

```js
// Prepare variables for popup and it's content
let popup;
let popupContent;

// Wait for DOM to get loaded
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){
  // Select all icons in DOM
  const icons = document.querySelectorAll('.js-icon');
  
  // Loop through the icons and add click event listener to each of them
  icons.forEach(icon => {
    icon.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
      // Get a content to be displayed in the popup
      const html = icon.querySelector('.js-icon-content').innerHTML;
      // Call openPopup and pass the HTML we got from icon's content
      openPopup(html);
    });
  })
  
  // Get popup and it's content and save it to the variable
  popup = document.querySelector('.js-popup');
  popupContent = popup.querySelector('.js-popup-content');
  
  // Add popup click event listener which closes the popup
  popup.addEventListener('click', closePopup);
  
  // Add click event listener for popup content which stops propagation. That means we do not want to close the modal, when someone clicks the popup content.
  popupContent.addEventListener('click', (e) => e.stopPropagation());
});

// Open the popup and add passed html in the popup content
function openPopup(html) {
  popup.classList.add('is-active');
  popupContent.innerHTML = html;
}

// Close popup, optionaly we might also clear the popup content's HTML.
function closePopup() {
  popup.classList.remove('is-active');
}
```

```css
.my-icon {
  padding: 10px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  margin: 0 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.my-icon div {
  display: none;
}

.popup {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.popup.is-active {
  display: flex;
}

.popup-content {
  background: white;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-icon js-icon">
  <span>Icon 1</span>
  <div class="js-icon-content">
    <h1>Hello world</h1>
    <p>I am simple content.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="my-icon js-icon">
  <span>Icon 2</span>
  <div class="js-icon-content">
    <h1>Hello world 2</h1>
    <p>I am simple content.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="popup js-popup">
  <div class="popup-content js-popup-content">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, David! I'll go trough this code in depth.